# Grab url till specific word

Tags: preg-match-all

I use a CSV import tool and did some research to grab the url out of the import result because it has a specific import syntax.

This is an example of an imported text.

... img src="MULTIFEED_START_7_http://www.suppliertestcase.com/423_1.jpgMULTIFEED_END_7_"

So I want to grab the image-url which is between the text MULTIFEED_START_7_  (could be 6 or 5, ... also) and the text MULTIFEED_END_7 (again could be 6 or 5, ...)

After some testing figured out that it works fine with :

preg_match_all('#(http://(.*).(gif|png|jpg))#i' , $post[0]->post_content , $matches);

Gets all url's correctly if it ends with .jpg, .gif or .png

Output is http://www.suppliertestcase.com/423_1.jpg

But ... yes now my problem.

Some suppliers give an product photo url in their import without .jpg or .gif extension.
They just give f.e this url (just directory url without file extension) :

img src="MULTIFEED_START_7_http://www.suppliertestcase.com/productphoto/MULTIFEED_END_7_"

So output of the grep should be http://www.suppliertestcase.com/productphoto/ 
How can i grab the url starting with http:// and everything before the MULTIFEED_END text?

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all('~(?<=(MULTIFEED_START_\d_))(.+)(?=(MULTIFEED_END_\d_))~',$src,$matches);
```

Try this.

Comment: Hi Mohammer,Thanks for your reply. 
I tried it with replacement $src to $post[0]->post_content but it doesn't work. 
However it is a good tip for me how to define the MULTIFEED_END_... end. I'll try several combinations with the original grep i use which works with .jpg, .gif or .png at the end

preg_match_all('#(http://(.*).(gif|png|jpg))#i' , $post[0]->post_content , $matches);

Comment: Thanks anyway Mohammer. 
As long the image-extensions are there following preg works perfect.

preg_match_all('#(http:\/\/(.*)\.(gif|png|jpg))#i' , $post[0]->post_content , $matches);

Grabs everything starting from http:// part till it detects .jpg or .gif or .png (.jpg or .gif or .png included in outpot result) 

I tried several combinations with the beginning part of the working preg_match_all and your (?=(MULTIFEED_END_\d_) definition to detect the MULTIFEED_END text but no result at this moment.

Comment: Hi Mohammer, Found it thanks to you. I just had to add a ? into the (.+) otherwise I had everything between the first MULTIFEED_START and the last MULTIFEED_END And I need the text between the first MULTIFEED_START and the first found MULTIFEED_END So this worked for me preg_match_all('~(?<=(MULTIFEED_START_\d_))(.+?)(?=(MULTIFEED_END_\d_))~',$src,$m‌​atches); Thanks a lot for your help.